# PHP Oracle display result

Tags: php, oracle

i have a problem displaying the result of a SQL query (against Oracle DB). My web page code is below. I am using tnsnames and run the webserver and the page on the oracle db server itself. Running the query in sqlplus/sql developer works fine.

TNSNAMES:

```
testdb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.10.101)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = testdb)
    )
  )
```

The page displays the 2 variables and afterwards directly the footer.

How can i display the returned data? Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

```
<head>
    <title>Reports</title>
    <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    <div id="main">
    <h1>Report1</h1>
    <h2>Report2</h2>
    <p>Report3</p>

    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['var1'])) {
    $var_storenr = $_GET['var1'];
    }

    if (isset($_GET['var2'])) {
    $var_storearea = $_GET['var2'];
    }

    echo "<p>Var 1: " . $var_storenr . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Var 2: " . $var_storearea . "</p>";

    $db_user='testusr';
    $db_pass='testusr';
    $db_name='testdb';
    $conn = oci_connect($db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    $query = 'select id_store, store_des from np_stores where id_store in ('.$var_storenr.') and id_region = '.$var_storearea.';';

    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($stid);

    echo "<table border='1'>\n";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    ?>

    <?php include("Footer.php"); ?>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out. It was a problem with the oracle connection, mainly PHP and x64 Oracle client.

installed x32 client and works fine.

Thanks,